# Paypal Payment via HTTP POST - on mobile website

Tags: post, mobile, paypal

I have a perfectly working `<form>` with `<input type="hidden" ...` as parameters to send POST request to PayPal to make payments possible. It works fine. But what should I change to redirect users on PayPal mobile site?

I've searched their APIs and for mobile website, and what I understand is that they recommend to use completely different method, some NVP. But how this could be that I cannot simply change my form?

Paypal mention [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECOnMobileDevices) to add parameter: `cmd=_express-checkout-mobile`, but when I add hidden input field with `_express-checkout-mobile` I get (mobile) message that transaction is invalid and please return to previous website.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cmd=_express-checkout-mobile` is for Mobile Express Checkout, which is the "some NVP method" you referred to.

Website Payments Standard (the product you're using) should - as of a few weeks ago - already give you a mobile checkout page; at least it does in my test: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=your-paypal-email&amount=1&item_name=Test

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't get those paypal names. So you say that it should be switched to mobile version automatically?

Comment: Wow, I've just realized that they just don't support mobile Opera (treating this like desktop browser). I've check on iPhone safari and it works well on mobile version :). Magic! Thx for saving hours of searching for problem that do not exist :)

Comment: I believe it's stock Android and Safari on iOS (either iPhone, iPad or iPod) at the moment, but since it's just launched I wouldn't be surprised to see additional support coming soon.